# Investigate the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{2^{n}\sin^{2n}{x}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Investigate the absolute convergence and the conditional convergence of the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\cdot\dfrac{2^{n}\sin^{2n}{x}}{n}$$
I don't have any idea. Please anyone help me.

Comment: What is $\sin^{2n} x$? Is it $(\sin x)^{2n}$?

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $t=2\sin^2 x$ and reduce your problem to oridinary power series